# Exchange 2010 mail enabled public folder migration to Exchange 2013

Tags: migration, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2013, public-folders

I have to migrate a couple of hundred mail-enabled public folders from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013. Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/public-folders/batch-migration-from-previous-versions?view=exchserver-2016&viewFallbackFrom=exchserver-2013) describes almost the complete migration process, except how to migrate the SMTP mail addresses to the new public folders.

My question is: Does those powershell scripts migrate the SMTP proxyaddresses, too or do I have to configure them manually afterwards?
If so, can you share some powershell commands or scripts to realize the mail capabilites, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not required, because the batch migration will transfer all mail addresses to the new Exchange server.